# Ocultar modelos en el home de la aplicación, django

Tags: python, django

Ustedes saben como quitar tantos modelos de la vista principal desde el home(osea los modelos en la aplicación)?
lo que pasa es que yo sólo quiero que sean visibles 5 modelos y en la vista me aparecen 10 modelos, quiero ocultarlos pero no sé ni por donde empezar.
Pongo la imagen para ilustrar más mi pregunta.
**Resumo: en clientes solo quiero dejar visibles 5 modelos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo estos me estorban en la vista, prefiero que se vean adentro de presupuestos y que dentro de presupuestos pueda agregar parte, mano de obra y subcontratar trabajos

> admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Parte, ParteAdmin)
admin.site.register(ManoObra, ManoObraAdmin)
admin.site.register(SubcontratarTrabajo, SubcontratarTrabajoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes remover los modelos que no deseas que sean vistos del archivo `admin.py`, cada aplicación tiene un archivo admin que se ve como lo siguiente:

```py
from .models import Author, Genre, Book, BookInstance

admin.site.register(Book)
# admin.site.register(Author)
# admin.site.register(Genre)
admin.site.register(BookInstance)
```

Debes remover los modelos que no desees o simplemente comentarlos como el ejemplo previo.

Comment: sólo que me aparece error si quito también el de subcontratarTrabajoAdmin y sí lo necesito para ir agregando cosas, así lo tengo en el archivo de admin.py: admin.site.register(SubcontratarTrabajo, SubcontratarTrabajoAdmin)

Comment: @AnaidBracho pero "si lo necesitas para ir agregando cosas" ¿Porqué lo quieres eliminar? No comprendo muy bien lo que tratas de plantear.

Comment: ah no lo que pasa es que quiero quitarlos de la vista principal por que parte, mano de obra y subcontratar trabajos deben estar dentro de presupuesto. Es que quiero meter los modelos dentro del modelo presupuesto en presupuesto dan clic a mano de obra y se pueden agregar cosas (aparecen 4 campos para llenar) y así para parte y subcontratar trabajos

Comment: Compreno lo que quieres, mira que según lo que he visto puedes tener una solución alterna siguiendo esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774872/1048404 hay otras que estan mejor valoradas pero no se aplican a tu caso por lo que deberías plantear mejor tu pregunta para obtener más ideas.

Comment: super! muchas gracias :) lo revisaré

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias!!! encontré la respuesta en el post, sólo tenía que añadir:     def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return False